# Create my own Model with node who allow new Model and Model.find()

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, model-view-controller, model

I'm trying to create a Model with node and I want to be able to use it like that :

**Require the models**

```
var Example = require('./models/example');
```

**Create new object**

The model can create a new object using `new`

```
var example = new Example({ data:'example' });
```

**Find**

The model can find object using method

```
Example.find({ data: 'mongoQuery' }, function(err, examples) {});
```

**Save**

The model can help to find object using method, who return object with methods.

```
Example.findOne({ query: 'example' }, function(err, example) {
  example.set({ data: 'another data' });
  example.save();
});
```

**Example of use**

I want to be able to create, find (one or multiple), uptade and delete a token (for example) using the model like that. I'll use that on controller or lib for example.

```
var Token = require('./models/token); 

// Create and save a new token
var new_token = new Token({ key: 'abcdef' });
new_token.save();

// find multiple tokens, update, and save
var token = Token.find({key: 'abcderf'}, function(tokens) {
  for(var i in tokens) {
    tokens[i].set({key: '123456'});
    tokens[i].save();
  }
});
```

I already try lots of thing, but I can't create a module who allow the `new Example` and `Example.find()` in the same time.

**Backbone :**

I have try using Backbone, the new Token({ /* attributes */ }) work but the find function return an error : `TypeError: Object function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'find'`

```
var Token = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function(attributes) {
    console.log("Token create");
    console.log(" attributes : ", attributes);
  },

  find : function(query, callback) {
    console.log("Token find");
    console.log(" query : ", query);
    callback(null, [ /* tokens */]);
  }
});
module.exports = Token;
```

**Object**

When I'm trying to use an object, the find function work well, but I can't use it with `new` returning the error : `TypeError: object is not a function`

```
module.exports = {

  find : function(query, callback) {
    console.log("[Step] models/token.js - find");
    console.log(" query : ", query);
    callback(null, []);
  }

};
```

What the best way to create a Model to handle all objects on controller ?

Thank for helping !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I create a model base on the @Neta Meta reply :

**./models/token.js**

```
var Backbone    = require('backbone');
var db          = require('../lib/database');

var Token = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(attributes) {
  },

  save: function(callback) {
    db.collection('tokens').insert(self.attributes, function(err) {
      if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback(err, self);
      }
    });
  }
});


module.exports.create = function(attr, callback) {
   callback(null, new Token(attr));
};

module.exports.findOne = function(query, callback) {
  db.collection('tokens').findOne(query, function(err, result) {
    callback(err, new Token(result));
  });
};
```

So now I can use it like that :

**./controllers/example.js**

```
var Token = require('../models/token');

// Create one :
Token.create({key: 'new data'}, function(err, token) {
  token.set({key: 'updated data'});
  token.save();
});

// Find one :
Token.findOne({key: 'updated data'}, function(err, token) {
  token.set({key: 're-updated data'});
  token.save(function(err) {
     console.log("Token saved");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
YourModule = function(data){
    this.data = data; // this.data is now a property of the object you create with New. 
};

YourModule.prototype.find = function(query, callback) {
    console.log("[Step] models/token.js - find");
    console.log(" query : ", query);
    callback(null, []);
    return this.data; // this.data is available here.
};

YourModule.prototype.save = function(data) {
    this.data = data; // this.data is available here to.
};


module.exports = YourModule;
```

You cannot instantiate an object using new keyword, you can however do `Object.create` to do so. i prefer my example though.

Comment: If I add an other method (like ` YourModule.prototype.save = function` ). The returned object on `find` can access to the `save()` function ? (each one independently ?)

Comment: you will have to have some properties defined inside the contractor and yes, i dont know what exactly you are trying to do with this model. is this modle a db model ? is it something you are making ? what will save function do?

Comment: But, I don't understand, if the `find` function return multiple object. How the save function will know which one save ?

Comment: arthur. i dont know what your find function does.. or what is this model you are making. explain more about your model.

Comment: Ok.. I'm sorry, english isn't my first language.. I have update my post to add am example how to use it.

Comment: arthur, your model is this a data base model ? by doing save - what happened ?

Comment: On models files i'll use mongodb to retrieve, store, validate... I want to use this is a day i want to change the database